# proving $(x^n)$ diverges for $x>1$

Tags: real-analysis

I got stocked to prove this fact $\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n=\infty$. I am assuming for a contradiction that $(x^n)$ convergence so for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\ge 1$ such that $|x^n-l|\le\epsilon$. 
Then I am thinking if I choose $\epsilon=x-L$ but that would not work since we can not guarantee that $x<l$, So could anyone please help me with this I would appreciate that?

Comment: So could anyone please help me with this I would appreciate that?

Comment: Your logic is insufficient. There are sequences that don't converge that also don't diverge to $\infty$.

Comment: For the sequence to converge, the difference between consecutive terms must converge to 0. (Why?) But here, that difference is $x^{n+1}-x^n = x^n(x-1)$. You should be able to bound this away from zero...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}  x^n = L
$$
we must also have
$$
xL = x \lim_{n \to \infty} x^n = \lim_{n \to \infty} x^{n+1} = L
$$
so $xL = L$, so $x = 1$ or $L = 0$.

Now use our assumption that $x > 1$, so $L = 0$.
But this is impossible, because $1 < x < x^2 < x^3 < \cdots$,
implying that $|x^n - 0| > 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: That is really helpful and clear, thank you

Comment: @Ahmed you're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

For a fixed $x>1$ we have $x-1>0$ and Bernoulli inequality shows
$$x^n=(1+x-1)^n\geq1+n(x-1)\geq n(x-1)$$

Comment: U mean use eps=n(x-1) will give a contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

when $x> 1$
we must show that:

$\forall M>0, \exists N>0: n>N \implies x^n > M$

let $N = \frac {M}{\ln x}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $M > 0$; let $x > 1$. Note that $x^{n} > M$ iff $n > (\log M)/(\log x)$. So taking $N$ to be the smallest integer no less than the log ratio suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be a real number greater than $1.$ Then the sequence $a_n:=x^n$ is strictly increasing, therefore, it diverges towards infinity if and only if; for any $M\in \textbf{R}$ there exists an $N\in\textbf{N}$ such that $a_N>M.$ Given any $M$, choosing $N>\log_x(M)$ will suffice.